# Extracting the numbers only from string using sed

Tags: regex, sed, extract

I have this string `Time:     4 days (361440 seconds)` and trying to extract only the number 361440 from this. I have gotten so far as to extract `361440 seconds` using `sed "s/.*(\(.*\))/\1/"` I keep going round in circles trying to just get the number from it.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is it that you're trying to extract? The second number in the string? The last number? The fourth word? The first word within the first pair of parentheses? The last number in the last pair of parentheses? The number in front of the word `seconds`? Something entirely different?

Comment: the last number "361440"

Comment: `grep -oP "(?<=\()[0-9]+(?=\))"`

Comment: Use `sed "s/.*(\([0-9]*\).*/\1/"`

Comment: Wiktor u man hit it on the head, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't explain the rule of extraction very clearly. Just based on your sed codes, this grep line should work for your example:

```
grep -oP '\(\K\d+'
```

Ok, then extend your sed one-liner a bit:

```
sed 's/.*(\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: my unix system which is unRaid does not reconise the -P comnmand on grep "grep: unrecognized option: P"